# Cant change Values of Array using assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
.586 ;Target processor. Use instructions for Pentium class machines
.MODEL FLAT, C ;Use the flat memory model. Use C calling conventions
.CODE ;Indicates the start of the code segment.

PUBLIC binarize
binarize PROC
push ebp
mov ebp,esp

;-------Variaveis----------
mov eax ,0; Counter
mov ebx, [ebp+8]; Limite
mov ecx, [ebp+12];ArrayChars
mov edx, [ebp+18];Tamanho
mov edi, 0
;--------------------------

LoopVer:
cmp [ecx+eax], ebx
jle elseloop
mov edi, 0
mov [ecx+eax], edi
jmp end_if
elseloop:
mov edi, 255
mov [ecx+eax], edi
end_if:
inc eax

cmp eax, edx
jne LoopVer
pop ebp
ret
binarize ENDP
END
}
```

Getting syntax error in expression in lines
mov [ecx+eax], edi

I have made a unsigned char array , a unsigned char, and a integer to loop.
I tryed moving 0 in hex to edi, and 255 in hex to edi, still the same error

Comment: Syntax error or a runtime error?  If ecx were somehow a bad pointer, I could see getting an exception when running.  if `cmp/mov [ecx+eax]` points to a portion of memory that is read only (if ArrayChars is constant) I could see you hitting an exception on the `mov` instruction.

Comment: There's no syntax error as far as I can tell. Well, that `}` is peculiar, but MASM seems to ignore it since it appears after `END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting syntax error in expression in lines `mov [ecx+eax], edi`

For a program that has `.586` the above instruction is correct.

What's more worrying is your use of *sizes*.

You invoke the *binarize* proc with 3 parameters: an unsigned char (*Limite*), an unsigned char array (*ArrayChars*), and an integer to loop (*Tamanho*).
The array consists of **bytes**, we see you use `inc eax`, but you compare and store **dwords**. This means that your code is wrong and could potentially trigger a segmentation fault while accessing 3 bytes past the array.

Also note, and this is maybe a typo, that the 3rd argument resides at `[ebp+16]` (not at `[ebp+18]`).

My rewrite follows:

```
  mov   dh, [ebp+8]    ; Limite
  mov   ecx, [ebp+12]  ; ArrayChars
  xor   eax, eax       ; Offset in the array

LoopVer:
  mov   dl, 0
  cmp   [ecx+eax], dh  ; DH is Limite
  jg    elseloop
  not   dl
elseloop:
  mov   [ecx+eax], dl  ; DL == {0,255}
  inc   eax
  cmp   eax, [ebp+16]  ; Tamanho
  jb    LoopVer
```

Remember that you're using `EAX` as **an offset measured in bytes from the start of the array**.